# Fortran Function that accepts different types

Tags: oop, fortran

I have a three convert functions that convert angles, the code shown below.

The functions returns are of the same type as the input. This means that
the input angle has either to be of the type the programmer wishes the output
to be or convert it to output type required using for example 
`al = convert(Real(30),"deg_to_rad")`.

I would like the programmer to be able to do `al = convert(30,"deg_to_rad")`.
I have the idea to use the strategy of the `transfer` intrinsic to define
the output type.

```
Real :: al, mold    
al = convert(30,"deg_to_rad", mold)
al = convert(30.0,"deg_to_rad", mold)

Double Precision :: al, mold    
al = convert(30,"deg_to_rad", mold)
al = convert(30.0,"deg_to_rad", mold)
```

There are the functions I have. Would be good to have some ideas
on ways to proceed and implement a good scheme.

```
Interface convert
  Module Procedure convert
  Module Procedure convert_real
  Module Procedure convert_dble
  Module Procedure convert_real128
End Interface convert

Contains

Function convert_real   &
  (                &
    qa, label      &
  )                &
 Result (qb)

Real, Intent (in) :: qa
Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

Real :: qb

If (label .contains. "angle:") Then

 Block

   Real :: pi, deg_to_rad

   pi = 22.0 / 7.0
   deg_to_rad  = pi  / 180.0

   Select Case (Trim (label))

     Case ("angle: deg_to_rad")
       qb = deg_to_rad * qa

   End Select

 End Block

End If

End Function convert_real


Function convert_dble  &
  (                    &
    qa, label          &
  )                    &
 Result (qb)

Double Precision, Intent (in) :: qa
Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

Double Precision :: qb


If (label .contains. "angle:") Then

 Block

   Double Precision :: pi, deg_to_rad

   pi = Dble(22) / Dble(7)
   deg_to_rad  = pi / Dble(180)

   Select Case (Trim (label))

     Case ("angle: deg_to_rad")
       qb = deg_to_rad * qa

   End Select

 End Block

End If

End Function convert_dble


Function convert_real128  &
  (                       &
    qa, label             &
  )                       &
 Result (qb)

Real (Real128), Intent (in) :: qa
Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

Real (Real128) :: qb

If (label .contains. "angle:") Then

 Block

   Real (Real128) :: pi, deg_to_rad
   pi = Real(22,Real128) / Real(7,Real128)
   deg_to_rad  = pi / Real(180,Real128)

   Select Case (Trim (label))

     Case ("angle: deg_to_rad")
       qb = deg_to_rad * qa

   End Select

 End Block

End If

End Function convert_real128
```

I am trying to use a subroutine when the input and outputs are of different
types. However I get the error below

```
Subroutine convertor  & 
  (                   &
    qa, label, qb     &
  )

Class (*), Intent (in) :: qa
Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

Class (*), Intent (out) :: qb

Select Type (qb)

 Type Is (Real)
   qb = convert (Real(qa),label)

 Type Is (Double Precision)
   qb = convert (Dble(qa),label)

 Type Is (Real (Real128))
   qb = convert (Real(qa,Real128),label)

End Select

End Subroutine convertor
```

Here is the error

```
gfortran -o build/lib/foul.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/foul.f
gfortran -o build/lib/meidum.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/meidum.f
lib/meidum.f:890.26:

   qb = convert (Real(qa),label)
                      1
Error: 'a' argument of 'real' intrinsic at (1) must be a numeric type
lib/meidum.f:893.26:

   qb = convert (Dble(qa),label)
                      1
Error: 'a' argument of 'dble' intrinsic at (1) must be a numeric type
lib/meidum.f:896.26:

   qb = convert (Real(qa,Real128),label)
                      1
Error: 'a' argument of 'real' intrinsic at (1) must be a numeric type
```

Comment: One of the problems is that I cannot use Class (*) for the result type of the function. Thus the code cannot use mold.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this seems unnecessarily complicated.  Instead of using `transfer` as your model, use the arithmetic intrinsic functions such as `sin`.  Fortran (since FORTRAN 77) can automatically distinguish between the various sine functions (real, double precision, quad precision) based on their argument.  Write each function, then an `interface` listing them as `module procedure` to make them generic.  Example: [Overloading functions with Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721961/overloading-functions-with-fortran)

EDIT:
It depends on what you want:

```
result = convert (input)
```

To me, it seems most natural to have type of the function return controlled by the type of the argument `input`.  That is what I described and is what is shown in the example.   If the type of `result` is different, Fortran will convert in the assignment ... the drawback is if you have selected compiler options so that this generates a warning.   So if instead you want the type of `result` to control the type calculated by `convert`, then this technique will have to be modified.  You can't use a function because function return doesn't distinguish for this overloading.   Use a subroutine instead, which will then have an argument that will distinguish:

```
call convert (input, result)
```

This will work just fine in with an interface / module procedure.   I'm not sure why think this won't work.   It might be a bit less elegant in usage than the assignment statement / function notation.

Comment: That is what I have been trying to do. I have a different function for real, double precision and real (real128). The input type has to be the same as the output for there functions to work. Need to perhaps have other functions that can take integer but output a real.

Comment: I cannot find a way how the function can know the return type, unless the programmner inputs variables.

Comment: I agree with @M.S.B.  Follow the example shown in the question pointed to.  Like the intrinsics such as `sin` have the function return the same kind as the argument passed.  If you want to cast the result to another kind (or type), do that explicitly, just as you would with `sin` etc.  As for using `TRANSFER`, how do you propose to take either the first 32-bits or last 32-bits of a 64-bit real and make them into a 32-bit real ?  Transfer doesn't type-cast, it just allows the programmer write potentially dangerous code to (mis-)interpret bits in memory.

Comment: The difference is that I would have to use a subroutine. However sin is a function. It returns the type depending on the input variable. I would need a small example.

Comment: Suppose I want to output a real, I have to do `real :: r = convert(Real(30),"deg_to_rad")`. I cannot have `r = convert(30,"deg_to_rad")` and expect it to return the same type as r.

Comment: The only way I see is to use a subroutine call when the input and output murt be of different types. I thought this might solce the problem until I remembered that I cannot have the subsoutine with the same name, because in an interface, the module procudures have to be all functions or all procedures. I cannot have the subroutine in there.

Comment: Note the analogy being made around `transfer` by the OP is with respect to the way its interface works, not its behaviour.  That is - transfer has the MOLD argument, and [in some ways] that argument is used to select the specific form of the generic transfer procedure to call and hence vary the type of the function's result.

Comment: Do you know how one can vary the type of the function's result from the specific form of mold?

Comment: I agree with MSB tnat I use a subroutine if the types are different. However, when I tried I got an error. This is shown in the updated code fragment.

Comment: You are still using CLASS(*).  That is not the appropriate language feature for this.  What this answer is basically telling you is that you need to write the specific function (or subroutine) for **each** **combination** **of** **types** that you want to support operations on.  If you want to use a MOLD argument to vary the result of a function call then you write a specific function for **each** **type** (and kind) that you want the MOLD to support.  This could end up requiring a lot of typing.  Tricks using INCLUDE can then be used to reduce the amount of code duplication.